# Why do these scope definitions have different behavior when used through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on upgrading to Rails 4 from Rails 3.  I have a scope definition that seems to be loosing the where clauses and other scopes that get applied.

I have these models:

```
class GoalWeightSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goal_weight_set_nutrients, -> {order(:nutrient_id).includes(:nutrient)}, :inverse_of=>:goal_weight_set, :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
end

class GoalWeightSetNutrient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal_weight_set, :inverse_of=>:goal_weight_set_nutrients

  scope :model_weights, -> {where(:index=>false)}
  scope :model, -> {where(:index => false)}
end
```

I see radically different behavior between using these two scopes in Rails 4

```
# this is broken, it should have a where clause
GoalWeightSet.first.goal_weight_set_nutrients.model.count
   (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "goal_weight_set_nutrients"
=> 37288

# this is what I expect 
GoalWeightSet.first.goal_weight_set_nutrients.model_weights.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "goal_weight_set_nutrients" WHERE "goal_weight_set_nutrients"."goal_weight_set_id" = $1 AND "goal_weight_set_nutrients"."index" = 'f'  [["goal_weight_set_id", 8]]
=> 31
```

The `scope :model` works fine in Rails 3.  Why is this scope trying to load all the objects? Is there something special about a scope named 'model'?

Here is a gist you can run that shows the bug: https://gist.github.com/johnnaegle/9647941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, "model" on an association means something different in Rails 4:

```
Klass.where("1=0").model
=> Klass(id: integer)
```

So effectively, you can't use model as a scope name.